# Keep Elixir Plug connection open in chunked mode

Tags: elixir

Is it possible to keep connection open for few seconds in chunked state?

In request I create few processes which takes lets say 5 seconds to finish and after that I want to send response via chunk to client, but connection is closed

I am testing this with postman and I have this headers:

> "Connection": "Keep-Alive", "Keep-Alive": "timeout=10000"

This is my minimized application, output is always "InitEnd" 
desired result is: "Init1234567789End" or something like this:

```
defmodule AlivePlug do
  import Plug.Conn

  def init(opts) do
    opts
  end

  def call(conn, _opts) do
    conn = send_chunked(conn, 200)
    # send initial chunk
    chunk(conn, "Init")

    pid = start_thread
    # create 10 async processes which does somthing for 5 seconds and then sends result via chunk
    1..10
    |> Enum.each(fn num -> 
      send pid, {conn, num}
    end)

    # send End as a symbol of last chunk
    chunk(conn, "End")
    conn
  end

  defp start_thread, do: spawn_link(fn -> thread_listener end)
  defp thread_listener do
    receive do
      {conn, num} ->
        :timer.sleep(5000)
        # problem is here :(
        # chunk returns {:error, :closed}
        {:error, :closed} = chunk(conn, "#{num}")
        thread_listener
      _ -> 
        thread_listener
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Would it be possible to just open up another connection instead to send your response through?

Answer (score 0):

As workaround, I'm using `conn` periodically.

```
receive do
  ...
  after 3000 ->
    # avoid connection close.
    # execute `chunk(conn, ".")` every 3000ms
    chunk(conn, ".")
end
```

As additional information, `chunk`'s 2nd argument should be not empty string.